# Woocommerce Product Search with Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi have a search form that is allows the user to input a keyword then select a taxonomy via dropdown list.  This is my form:

```
    <form name="myCity" id="myCity" action="http://mywebsite.com/"  method="post">

<div class="search-area">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row-fluid">
           <div class="span4">
                <label><i class="icon-search"></i></label>
                <div class="search-area-division search-area-division-input">
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="I am searching for..."/>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <label><i class="icon-map-marker"></i></label>

            <?php
$args = array('taxonomy' => 'pa_city');
wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
    ?>

            </div>
        </div>           
                <noscript><input type="hidden" onclick="WriteCookie()" class="btn btn-block btn-white search-btn"  value="<?php echo esc_attr__( 'Search' ); ?>"/></noscript>
                <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />

    </div>
    </div>
```

If I search mini-golf in Bullhead City,

it returns the URL:
http://mywebsite.com/?s=mini-golf&cat=14&post_type=product

While it returns products with the tag mini-golf, it returns all products regardless of city that match mini-golf.  I have tried many ways to filter the results and am just spinning my wheels at this point.

The taxonomy I am using is pa_city.  Even if the url is
http://mywebsite.com/?s=mini-golf&pa_city=bullhead-city&post_type=product

it does the same thing.

No matter which way I write this, it will NOT exclude the other cities in the search.  Should I try a NOTIN?  I can't figure out why it brings all products regardless of city...

Answer (score 0):

I needed to filter the query further in my functions.php using pre_get_posts

Whew, that was a frustrating one.

```
    function my_location( $q ){
if (!$q->is_main_query() ) 
    return;
if ($q->is_search()) {
            $city = isset( $_COOKIE['city'] ) ? $_COOKIE['city'] : 'not set';

        $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(          'taxonomy' => 'pa_city',            'field' => 'slug',          'terms' => array( $city ),          'operator' => 'IN'      )));    
    return; 
    }
if ($q->is_archive() ){ 
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {           
            if (empty($_COOKIE['city'] )) {
                echo "<script>window.location.href = 'http://mywebsite.com/select-city/';</script>";
                exit();
            }
        $city = isset( $_COOKIE['city'] ) ? $_COOKIE['city'] : 'not set';

        $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(          'taxonomy' => 'pa_city',            'field' => 'slug',          'terms' => array( $city ),          'operator' => 'IN'      )));    
    }}
}

    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_location' );
```